# Return inner list if specified condition met - list comprehension

Tags: python

Given that `clusterLists` is a list of lists containing tuples

```
clusterLists = [[(1.182, "monthly_1.182"), (1.181, '1_Retrace_50_D')], [(1.1502, '1_Retrace_50_D'), (1.1493, '1_Retrace_50_M')]]


len(clusterLists)
2
```

At present the following list comprehension will return a list of lists if a string from the list `['daily','weekly','monthly']` is found:

```
[[ld for ld in cList
  if any(k in ld[1] for k in ['daily','weekly','monthly'])] for cList in clusterLists]
```

How do I modify this to return the original format (list of lists containing tuples) and with the following **desired output**:

```
[[(1.182, 'monthly_1.182'), (1.181, '1_Retrace_50_D')]]
```

The original format should be preserved.  If an inner list contains the search string in a tuple all tuples from the inner list element are returned.

Comment: Did you mean: `[[ld for ld in cList ...`?

Comment: Yes thanks question modified

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following one-liner solution:

```py
fl = [cluster for cluster in clusterLists if any([keyword in cluster_element[1] for cluster_element in cluster for keyword in ['daily','weekly','monthly']])]
```

However, I would advise to use a more readable solution by splitting it into several lines :

```py
FREQUENCIES = ['daily','weekly','monthly']
filtered_clusters = []
for cluster in clusterLists:
    for cluster_element in cluster:
        if any([freq in cluster_element[1] for freq in FREQUENCIES]):
            filtered_clusters.append(cluster)
            break
```

Comment: "use a more readable solution by splitting it" - could you post such, to make it easier for other people to understand your code ?

Comment: Your second snippet is not equivalent. You can end up appending `cluster` many times. Perhaps you could add a `break` as the last line.

Comment: Oups, you are definitely right, just edited it